# Installing node with nave

Tags: raspbian, node.js

Can nodejs be installed via nave on your raspberry ?

Does node 0.10.x is working fine when installed this way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not used it on the pi, but there's a node binary in the raspbian repository:

```
» apt-cache show nodejs
Package: nodejs
Version: 0.6.19~dfsg1-6
Architecture: armhf
Maintainer: Debian Javascript Maintainers <pkg-javascript-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
```

You should be able to install this very easily with `apt-get install nodejs`.  The version is more than 6 months old, however.

If that isn't good enough, the node.js crew themselves appear to maintain more recent versions pre-compiled for the pi:

http://nodejs.org/dist/

Currently, the "latest" version links to 0.10.3, for which there is no pi binary.  However, there's one for [0.10.2](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.2/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz), and there's also one for [0.11.0](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.11.0/node-v0.11.0-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz).  Nodejs follows an [odd/even version numbering](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Contributing) meaning the odd minor numbers are the development branch and the even ones the stable branch.  Most people will want the stable.

Those tarballs contain a directory tree:

```
bin/
lib/
share/
```

You can unpack this into `/usr/local/` on the pi.  *As root* (or with sudo):

```
mv node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz /usr/local/src
tar -xzvf node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz
cd /usr/local/src/node-v0.10.2-linux-arm-pi
mv bin/* ../../bin/
mv lib/* ../../lib/
```

Check if you have a /usr/local/share/man/man1, and if not:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man1
```

Once that's there:

```
mv share/man/man1/* ../../share/man/man1/
```

Done.  Check:

```
> file /usr/local/bin/node
node: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.1.10, not stripped
```

Should work, and it does; `node` on the command line acts as a javascript interpreter.  If you've already used node on linux you are good to go.  If not, you do not need to use a pi centric tutorial, the oodles that apply to linux generally should be fine.  However, worth mentioning is [this blog post](http://blog.rueedlinger.ch/2013/03/raspberry-pi-and-nodejs-basic-setup/) about setting up a node server to run as a boot service, etc, specifically for the pi.  Note that the author of that installs into a dedicated `/opt/node` directory and not `/usr/local`.

Comment: I've used this link http://blog.rueedlinger.ch/2013/03/raspberry-pi-and-nodejs-basic-setup/, it explains how to install the binaries.

Comment: @Luc : Hey that's great, I've added some stuff about that.

Answer (score 1):

[Node.js can be installed on the Pi](http://blog.tomg.co/post/21322413373/how-to-install-node-js-on-your-raspberry-pi).

I am not sure about your second question though, I will edit this answer as more info comes up.

This is how you do it:

1. First we need to download the SSL dev libraries.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
   ```
2. Now we need to download the latest stable release of Node.js

   ```
   wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.15/node-v0.6.15.tar.gz
   tar -xf node-v0.6.15.tar.gz
   cd node-v0.6.15
   export CCFLAGS='-march=armv6'
   export CXXFLAGS='-march=armv6'
   ```
3. We will use the `nano` text editor to edit a file.

   ```
   nano deps/v8/SConstruct
   ```
4. Edit lines 82 and 83 to match the following:

   ```
    'all': {
      'CCFLAGS':      ['$DIALECTFLAGS', '$WARNINGFLAGS', '-march=armv6'],
      'CXXFLAGS':     ['-fno-rtti', '-fno-exceptions', '-march=armv6'],
    },
   ```
5. Then comment out lines 157 - 162
6. Now comes the longest step.

   ```
    make
    make install
   ```
7. Lastly, do write this in the terminal:

   ```
   pacman -S nodejs
   ```

That should install `node.js` I have not tested it, but it should work. [Here is my source.](http://blog.tomg.co/post/21322413373/how-to-install-node-js-on-your-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I'll try it. I hope the automated installed using nave will be available soon on raspberry though :)

Comment: Latest node is 0.10.x

Comment: Also: Looks like node maintains binaries for the pi in that http://nodejs.org/dist/ repository, so you don't have to compile it from source (unless you want to).